# My touchpad on my ASUS K55N is not being detected

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchpad, trackpad

To preface this, I couldn't get my FN keys to work for a few days after finally installing ubuntu and after a whole day of a black screen on start up, my fn keys starting working, but my trackpad stopped.

I've tried checking for it under

> $ xinput list

but there is no touchpad that is being detected.

I've only had Ubuntu for about a week so far and I've had nothing but problems, so if anyone knows what's wrong it would be greatly appreciated. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
sudo modprobe -rv psmouse
sudo modprobe -v psmouse
```

It will remove-reload the psmouse driver which controls the touchpad in asus laptops.

If that does not help, try:

```
echo "blacklist asus_nb_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then reboot and see if it helps.

The "asus_nb_wmi" driver mainly controls the wifi and bluetooth switch, but in combination of some other drivers, it also controls some other Fn+ hotkeys, including enable/disable touchpad.

Disabling it will also disable some Fn+ key combinations, so this is just for a test. To remove it from blacklist to make it work again:

```
sudo sed -i "/asus_nb_wmi/ d" /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Although since your touchpad is entirely disappeared, I doubt if any of these trivial workarounds are going to fix it, but testing won't hurt. Maybe another update would fix it automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those worked. It's strange though since before my laptop decided to not start for a day, my trackpad was working great and fn keys didn't work at all..

Comment: Interestingly enough, the blacklist did fix my fn keys for the brightness, which were the only fn keys that weren't working. It did disable the function for the touchpad though